# Texture resolution for big objects

Tags: modeling, texturing, resolution

I apologize at once for a possibly stupid question. But I have this question. Suppose we have a model of a building for the game, let's say the texture of the building at the player's eye level will be in high resolution, but then how to make sure that the top of the building has a texture with low resolution, while not showing a sharp transition between the two textures. I assume I have to divide the model into several parts and the higher the part from the player, the resolution of the textures bklt less, as well as the level of detail. Am I right? And how to choose the right place where there will be this transition texture?

Comment: hello and welcome, this question doesn't really seem to be about blender lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ussually this is handled by game engine automatically. In Blender it was previously handled by **[MIP map](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/textures/types/image/options.html)** feature to speedup viewport, but again it was automatically generated by app.
So probably let us know - What is your specific use case ... What app is going to be used for your textures?*

---

Just for a curiosity ...

For simple objects like skyscrapers you can create a classic material with even *UVmap* ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

... than create another *UVmap* squeezed by **Proportional Editing** enabled under UV editor ...

[image]

Under Shader add another free *Image Texture* (for baking keep selected) with squeezed *UVmap* assigned.

[image]

*Bake* it and use as source texture for material ...

[image]

... like that upper floors take a fragment of pixels than lower floor close to viewer in baked texture, but from street level it will looks fine.

[image]

[image]

Note: To bake it properly ...

- *Image Texture* node you are baking at, has to be selected (active) in shader node tree
- to bake from original *UVmap* to sqeezed *UVmap* keep in mind - original *UVmap* has to have a render icon ON and squeezed *UVmap* has to be selected in the list - grayed row (it was painful discovery for me :) ) ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That is good information